# How to add menu for AutoCAD 2000 with Visual studio 6?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, autocad

I need a help for Visual studio 6 and AutoCAD 2000.

I have some source codes for adding menu for AutoCAD 2000. However, I just have code and no background knowledge about it.

First of all, I cannot compile code with Visual studio 6. I know that AutoCAD 2000 is compatible with compiled file from only Visual studio 6. I have succeeded compiling codes with VS2019, VS2010 and VS2008. However, compiled ARX file is not compiled with AutoCAD 2000. So, I need to compile codes with Visual studio 6 but I failed to do it.

The error codes are "C2065 : 'fopen_s': undeclared identifier". Actually, every secure function(_s) like fopen_s, sprintf_s, and so on causes error for compiling in Visual studio 6. I think secure function cannot be compiled in Visual studio 6.

I'm in a frustrated situation. AutoCAD 2000 is only compatible with Visual studio 6 but my code including secure function is not compiled in Visual studio 6. I'm absolutely sure that my codes were used for AutoCAD 2000.

Do you guys have any idea for compiling codes including secure function in Visual studio 6? or any idea adding menu in AutoCAD 2000 with other version of Visual studio?

Comment: ***The error codes are "C2065 : 'fopen_s': undeclared identifier". Actually, every secure function(_s) like fopen_s, sprintf_s, and so on causes error for compiling in Visual studio 6*** Visual Studio 6 did not have any of the secure functions (they came out many years later) so if you are using them you need to go back and use the standard.

Comment: This said the security functions were added in Visual Studio 2005: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0eb0b4f6-995e-45bc-80ec-2511bf38dbcc/vc6-sprintfs-errnot-etc?forum=vcgeneral](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0eb0b4f6-995e-45bc-80ec-2511bf38dbcc/vc6-sprintfs-errnot-etc?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: Visual Studio 6? AutoCAD 2000? You come from a distant past...